# Относительно invokeLater

Tags: java

Объясните новичку в области JAVA что означает данная фраза:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run(){
      ....
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

InvokeLater помещает выполняемую единицу, Runnable, в очередь событий - event dispatch thread. В эту же очередь помещаются все действия, связанные с обработкой событий, например. Затем, когда наступает ваша очередь, вызывается метод run у обьекта Runnable. Используется тогда, когда требуется отложенное действие, либо необходимо выполнить что-то строго в UI-thread`e.